# Django Post Request to Detail Page (Id)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to make a Django post request to specific url with a pk. So I have a list of projects and inside every project there are tasks. I want to add a task to that specific project.

This is the View function to create a normal project:

```
@login_required
def create_project(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    name = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Name')
    description = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Description') 
    parent_assignment = Assignment.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('Studyplan-PAID'))
    usernames = request.POST.getlist('Studyplan-Canview')
    users = User.objects.filter(username__in=usernames)
    userprofiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__in=users)
    project = Project(name=name, description=description, parent_assignment=parent_assignment)
    project.save()
    project.canview.set(userprofiles)
    project.members.set(userprofiles)

    return redirect('allProjects')
```

This is the project: 
[image]

When I tap this I get a detail page with a lot of tasks:
This is a task:

[image]

So as you can see every project has multiple tasks:

This is my attempt at doing a post request to tasks. My problem is that the task is not connected to the id of the project:

```
@login_required
def create_task(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    name = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Name')
    description = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Description') 

    usernames = request.POST.getlist('Studyplan-Canview')
    users = User.objects.filter(username__in=usernames)
    userprofiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__in=users)

    task = Task(name=name, description=description, state="new")
    task.save()
    task.canview.set(userprofiles)
    task.workers.set(userprofiles)

    return redirect('allaStudieplaner')
```

So this is aa picture from the admin page. I am inside the project and I want the task to be selected here:

[image]

Comment: you're not showing how you're passing the id of the project to the view, or what you're trying to do to associate the task with a project. `task.project = Project.objects.get(id=<some_id_from_the_request>)` or something like that is missing in your view.

Comment: in the post I didn't show it but I can now parse the id of the study plan into the view. But my problem is that task is a value in project but not the other way around so I can't to task.project, that dosen't exist :)

Comment: what's the relationship between Task and Project in your models? You said a project can have many tasks, then it would be logical that `Task` has a `ForeignKey` to `Project`.

Comment: Every Project has multiple task, so inside the project model there is a ManyToManyField to tasks